# XML, XDocument.Parse and foreach XElement

Tags: c#, xml

I made XML file today for my C# application.
XML (i putted in pastebin, 'cause its kinda big xml code, sorry):  [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/6UKgaULe)
and a code inside of C#

```
private void web_DownloadStringCompleted(object sender, DownloadStringCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Error == null)
    {
        XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);

        foreach (XElement xe in doc.Root.Element("builds").Element("build").Element("items").Elements("item"))
        {
            string s0 = xe.Element("name").ToString();
            string s1 = xe.Element("uri").ToString();
            string[] s2 = new string[2];

            s2[0] = s0;
            s2[1] = s1;
            ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(s2);
            listView1.Items.Add(lvi);
        }

    }
}
```

And I get error - `Object reference not set to an instance of an object.` or sometimes its not showing at all

Comment: Debug your code. One of the `.Element(name)` returns null. So `null.SomeMethod` would throw that exception.

Comment: try just doc.Descendants("name");

Comment: @I4V Debugging doesn't give to me any sense

Comment: @user2713690 So you want me to do it for you?

Comment: There are no `items` nodes or `item` nodes in your XML file, and therefore you are getting a null.

Comment: @Jonesy, Descendants still give same error.

Comment: @ChuckSavage OMG! How I wasn't seeing this, Thanks. :D Errr? Still same error.

Comment: Added my comment as an answer if you want to mark it as the answer.

Comment: I like using xpath: foreach (var element in doc.XPathSelectElements("builds/build/files/file"))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no `items` nodes or `item` nodes in your XML file, and therefore you are getting a null.

Comment: Thanks, but changing to `files` and `file`, which is in XML file, i'm still getting same error! Edit: Fixed.